# Poker, probability of players true raising frequency

Tags: probability, poker

The game is texas holdem, you get dealt two cards out of a 52 card deck. Hence there are 1326 possible combinations of two cards you can get.

Let's say our opponent has oppened the pot with a raise 5 out 10 possible times (50%).
Can we calculate the probability of this being his true raising frequenzy?

Edit:
Sorry for not being clear.
What i'm looking to do is determine how many hands you need on a opponent to have trustworthy statistics. If a opponent has raised first in 50%, we will assume it's hands in the top 50% of starting hands (equity wise). Can we make a 95% confidence interval of his raising frequency?

Comment: Please define "true raising frequency".

Comment: If you didn't see any of your opponent's hands, then $50\%$ likelihood of raising is the best you can say. If you saw some of the hands, then you can say more (under the assumption that your opponent isn't raising haphazardly). For example, if you opponent raised often with weak hands, then probably the likelihood of a raise is higher than $50\%$.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking might be better off at the statistics stackexchange site, but I'll answer with the best of my (probably slightly hazy) statistical knowledge.

You're asking for a interval with which you can estimate the opponents preflop raising percentage. While in your example it is remarkably high (50% of all hands would include some pretty rubbish hands), the incredibly small sample of 10 hands is almost certainly the reason for this.

Let p = proportion of hands the opponent raises preflop with. 
You don't know p, you only have an estimate, which we can call $q$.

$q$ has an expected value, of $q$ (this seems self explanatory and i'll explain why this needs to be said). $q$ is not the real proportion, it is only an estimate based on a random sample. Therefore if you had seen a different sample of 10 hands, your $q$ would be different. The standard deviation of your $q$ is given by:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{q(1-q)}{n}} $$

A 95% confidence interval is 1.96 standard deviations either side of the mean, so your confidence interval is $q$ plus or minus 1.96 times this standard deviation. I'll let you substitute your values in, but you'll find you'll need a bigger sample to get a good answer of the opponents aggression.

Comment: If it's not clear, in your example q is 0.5

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Didn't know there was a statistics stackexchange site as well, will use that next time.

Obviously 10 hands is way too small sample, I just took something as an example.
Alot of poker players use programs that provide statistics over opponents, but it's not clear how many hands you need to have useful statistics. Therefor this question.